# create folder from a list

Tags: windows, scripting, batch

i need to create a personal folder for each user of my company.

I've tried to create a batch script using **ND** command and it works just with name folder without . (dot)

The name of each folder should be **name.surname**

```
   ND jonny.green,
   micheal.fox,
   laura.young
```

Do you have some suggestion ?

Comment: My windows CMD does not even know the command "nd". Where did you get this? Is it part of Windows?

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a file with the usernames, this is pretty easy with Powershell (which is integrated with Windows since Windows 7/2008R2):

```
Get-Content yourfilewithusernames.txt | %{New-Item -ItemType Directory $_}
```

Basically, you get the content of the file and pass it to the pipeline; then, for each element/line (operator `%`), you create a new folder which name will be the content of that line (operator `$_`).

Answer (score 0):

1. create file **lists.txt** for all users that you need to create folder
2. copy and save as FolderMaker.cmd

   SET _dest=P:\PersonalFolders

   SET _script=C:\Scripts
   path=C:\Windows\System32\

   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%_script%\list.txt) do md %_dest%\%%a

run with admin right